Kerberos checksum failed in Keycloak docker container
Struggling for days now regarding the setup of Kerberos in a Keycloak 24.x docker container.
What I've done so far :

Creating a custom image installing krb5-workstation in my image
Mounting an existing (and working) /etc/krb5.conf to run container (docker swarm)

However when setting every Kerberos settings to my new Keycloak, it fails flawlessly with error :
 Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator false KeyTab is /var/kerberos/keycloak/keycloak.keytab_AES refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/keycloak.contoso.net@CONTOSO.NET tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
 principal is HTTP/keycloak.contoso.net@CONTOSO.NET
 Will use keytab
 Commit Succeeded

 2024-06-11 00:00:07,379 WARN  [org.keycloak.federation.kerberos.impl.SPNEGOAuthenticator] (executor-thread-1) SPNEGO login failed: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)
         at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:716)
         [...]
         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
 Caused by: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)
         at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:864)
         [...]
         at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
         ... 25 more
 Caused by: KrbException: Checksum failed
         at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.java:102)
         [...]
         at java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:837)
         ... 35 more
 Caused by: java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Checksum failed
 [...]
 at java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.java:100)
         ... 41 more

                 [Krb5LoginModule]: Entering logout
                 [Krb5LoginModule]: logged out Subject
 2024-06-11 00:00:07,385 WARN  [org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.SpnegoAuthenticator] (executor-thread-1) Received kerberos token, but there is no user storage provider that handles kerberos credentials.

I've tested my keytab using two methods :
1/ kinit & klist which seems to work
bash-5.1$ kinit -v -k -t /var/kerberos/keycloak/keycloak.keytab_AES HTTP/keycloak.contoso.net@CONTOSO.NET
bash-5.1$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: HTTP/keycloak.contoso.net@CONTOSO.NET

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
06/11/2024 00:14:47  06/11/2024 10:14:47  krbtgt/CONTOSO.NET@CONTOSO.NET
        renew until 06/18/2024 00:14:47

2/ Using a Java piece of code provided in another SO answer but adapted to take Keycloak parameters (to work in same condition):
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.security.auth.Subject;

import com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule;

/**
 * This is simple Java program that tests ability to authenticate 
 * with Kerberos using the JDK implementation.
 * 
 * The program uses no libraries but JDK itself.
 */
public class Krb {

  private void loginImpl(final String propertiesFileName) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("NB: system property to specify the krb5 config: [java.security.krb5.conf]");
    //System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/etc/krb5.conf");

    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));

    System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");

    final Subject subject = new Subject();

    final Krb5LoginModule krb5LoginModule = new Krb5LoginModule();
    final Map<String,String> optionMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    if (propertiesFileName == null) {
      //optionMap.put("ticketCache", null);

      optionMap.put("keyTab", "/var/kerberos/keycloak/keycloak.keytab_AES");
      optionMap.put("principal", "HTTP/keycloak.contoso.net@CONTOSO.NET"); // default realm

      optionMap.put("doNotPrompt", "true");
      optionMap.put("refreshKrb5Config", "false");
      optionMap.put("useTicketCache", "false");
      optionMap.put("renewTGT", "false");
      optionMap.put("useKeyTab", "true");
      optionMap.put("storeKey", "true");
      optionMap.put("isInitiator", "false");
      optionMap.put("tryFirstPass", "false");
      optionMap.put("useFirstPass", "false");
      optionMap.put("storePass", "false");
      optionMap.put("clearPass", "false");
    } else {
      File f = new File(propertiesFileName);
      System.out.println("======= loading property file ["+f.getAbsolutePath()+"]");
      Properties p = new Properties();
      InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
      try {
        p.load(is);
      } finally {
        is.close();
      }
      optionMap.putAll((Map)p);
    }
    optionMap.put("debug", "true"); // switch on debug of the Java implementation

    krb5LoginModule.initialize(subject, null, new HashMap<String,String>(), optionMap);

    boolean loginOk = krb5LoginModule.login();
    System.out.println("======= login:  " + loginOk);

    boolean commitOk = krb5LoginModule.commit();
    System.out.println("======= commit: " + commitOk);

    System.out.println("======= Subject: " + subject);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("A property file with the login context can be specified as the 1st and the only paramater.");
    final Krb krb = new Krb();
    krb.loginImpl(args.length == 0 ? null : args[0]);
  }
}

which results in success:
[...]
======= login:  true
Commit Succeeded

======= commit: true
======= Subject: Subject:
        Principal: HTTP/keycloak.contoso.net@CONTOSO.NET
        Private Credential: /var/kerberos/keycloak/keycloak.keytab_AES for HTTP/keycloak.contoso.net@CONTOSO.NET

Any help would be much appreciated. Don't know why it seems to work using 1/ & 2/ but not in keycloak (checksum failed).

Did you reissue the keytab at any time during the migration?

Yes to change hostname

Same issue with previous keytab

Does the issue remain if you log out from Windows, then log in again, after a keytab change?

Yes it does remain
